# Partial orders on tabloids

Tags: rt.representation-theory, order-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\lambda \vdash n$, a partition of $n$. By a $\lambda$-tabloid I mean a *row*-tabloid of shape $\lambda$. There is a well-known order on the set of $\lambda$-tabloids, coming from an order on the set of *compositions* of $n$. It is a partial order and is also called the *dominance order*, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_order) for its definition on partitions.

**Question**: besides the dominance order, are there any other interesting partial orders on the set of tabloids?

The reason that I am interested in considering other partial orders, is because of the following lemma, which is Lemma 2.5.8. on page 69 of Sagan's book 'The Symmetric Group'. Here, $\mu$ is a partition of $n$ and $M^{\mu}$ is the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space spanned by all $\mu$-tabloids. We say that a tabloid $\{t\}$ *appears* in a vector $v = \sum_{T}c_{T}\{T\} \in M^{\mu}$, if the coefficient $c_{t} \neq 0$. In the lemma, the dominance order on the set of tabloids is used. However, it remains true for any partial order on tabloids.

**Lemma**: Let $v_{1},...,v_{m}$ be elements of $M^{\mu}$. Suppose, for each $v_{i}$ there is a tabloid $\{t_{i}\}$ appearing in $v_{i}$ such that

1. $\{t_i\}$ is maximum in $v_i$, and
2. the $\{t_i\}$ are all distinct.

Then $v_{1},...,v_{m}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: I think the following linear order, which is much simpler, also good for the proof of the Lemma 2.5.8: The first integer in different rows of the two given tabloids appears first in the larger one.